# How can I get the all Ids after persiting with doctrine using batch procces?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm using the batch processing to improve my performance. It means that I'm inserting my object after making 50 like you can see in the code. However I need to recover all of Ids of these objects because I need to save some photos. (I use the ID for making the name of the photos)

```
    ...

    $em->persist($contact);

                    if(($k % $batchsize)===0){
                        $em->flush();
                        $user_id=$user->getId();
                        $em->clear();
                        $user=$userManager->findById($user_id);
                    }
                    $k++;
}
```

Does anyone know how can I recover the ids after doing this process?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after your comment :

I recommend to you to create a postFlush listener. With that, you can retrieve all your entities inserted and play with these :

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use AppBundle\Entity\Contact;

class ContactInserts {
    public function postFlush(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        foreach ($em->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
            if ($entity instanceof Contact) {

                //... Do what you want to do with your contact ($entity) ...
                $em->persist($entity);
            }
        }
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

And in your `service.yml` or `config.yml̀

```
services:
    my.listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\ContactInserts
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postFlush }
```

But care because you've some logic problems in your code below :

```
...            
$em->persist($contact);
// /!\ If you don't have a 49 contacts left, these won't be flushed
if(($k % $batchsize)===0) {
     $em->flush();
     $em->clear();
     /* I can't understand what you're doing here sorry */
     $user_id=$user->getId(); //You use user to get the id
     $user=$userManager->findById($user_id); //You use the just retrieved id to get the user ???                   
}
$k++;
```

Comment: I want the contacts Ids. Uhe user Id is the same all the time because the owner of the contacts is the user. I can't get the contacts Ids because the contacts ids is made once the contact is inserted in the DDBB. I didn't set all of the code because is pretty long I thought that code was enought to understand the logic, so sorry and thanks for answering :)

Comment: I update my answer with a solution post flush which fit better with your problem ;)

Comment: I know, but there is another flush after the loop. However where do I have to put the listener to make work this function. Could you write the full script with the imports and the namespace please?

Comment: I'm too kind. But here it is. ;)